# "Abstract member cannot be accessed directly" for KeyEvent

Tags: android, kotlin, android-softkeyboard

I'm implementing a [key listener](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/commands#SingleKey) to detect when someone clicks a backspace:

```
class MapFragment : Fragment(), View.OnClickListener, KeyEvent.Callback {

    override fun onKeyUp(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
        return when (keyCode) {
            KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL -> {
                enterCode1.text?.clear()
                enterCode2.text?.clear()
                enterCode3.text?.clear()
                enterCode3?.isEnabled = true
                enterCode2?.isEnabled = true
                enterCode1?.isEnabled = true
                enterCode1?.requestFocus()
                true
            }
            else -> super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event)
        }
    }
}
```

Even though I've taken the exact sample from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/commands#SingleKey) - `super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event)` returns the following compiler error:

```
Abstract member cannot be accessed directly
```

Why is this?

Comment: Because you don't have any function named onKeyUp in `Fragment`, it is an abstract method provided by `KeyEvent.Callback` you are overriding. There is a [onKeyUp](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onKeyUp(int,%20android.view.KeyEvent)) in `Activity` which that doc was referring to.

Comment: Ok thanks. How can I call the super on `onKeyUp` in my Fragment? @AnimeshSahu

Comment: There's no super function called `onKeyUp` in Fragment...